# Convert sequential loop into parallel in C using pthreads

Tags: c, loops, parallel-processing, pthreads

I would like to apply a pretty simple straightforward calculation on a `n`-by-`d`-dimensional array. The goal is to convert the sequential calculation to a parallel one using `pthreads`. My question is: **what is the optimal way to split the problem**? **How could I significantly reduce the execution time of my script**? I provide a sample sequential code in C and some thoughts on parallel implementations that I have already tried.

```
double * calcDistance(double * X ,int n, int d)
{
    //calculate and return an array[n-1] of all the distances
    //from the last point
    double *distances = calloc(n,sizeof(double));
    for(int i=0 ; i<n-1; i++)
    {
        //distances[i]=0;
        for (int j=0; j< d; j++)
        {

            distances[i] += pow(X[(j+1)*n-1]-X[j*n+i], 2);

        }
        distances[i] = sqrt(distances[i]);


    }
    return distances;
}
```

I provide a `main()`-caller function in order for the sample to be complete and testable:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 10 //00000
#define D 2        

int main()
{

    srand(time(NULL));

    //allocate the proper space for X
    double *X = malloc(D*N*(sizeof(double)));

    //fill X with numbers in space (0,1)
    for(int i = 0 ; i<N ; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<D; j++)
        {
            X[i+j*N] = (double) (rand()  / (RAND_MAX + 2.0));
        }

    }
    X = calcDistances(X, N, D);

    return 0;
}
```

- I have already tried utilizing `pthreads` asynchronously through the use of a `global_index` that is imposed to `mutex` and a `local_index`. Through the use of a `while()` loop,  a `local_index` is assigned to each thread on each iteration. The `local_index` assignment depends on the `global_index` value at that time (both happening in a `mutual exclusion` block). The thread executes the computation on the `distances[local_index]` element.
  Unfortunately this implementation has lead to a much slower program with a x10 or x20 bigger execution time compared to the sequential one that is cited above.
- Another idea is to predetermine and split the array (say to four equal parts) and assign the computation of each segment to a given `pthread`. I don't know if that's a common-efficient procedure though.

Comment: The best implementation for any parallel problem, including this one, is one that will minimize the number of resource contention and one that makes best use of cache. Cache consideration is more important than you might think, since reads from disk are order of magnitudes slower. Also, if two threads write / read to and from the same cache line, a thread writing will invalidate other threads' caches. This can also happen with "false sharing", where no actual data is being shared by threads, but happens to be writing to the same cache line.

Comment: @0x534f53 How do I prevent "false sharing"? In order to prevent resource contention, should I predetermine the segments of the array to be computed like I suggested on the second bullet?

Comment: Yes. We ideally want only one thread writing into each memory location and cache block, as to not invalidate other thread's caches. Taking a step even further, we can improve it further by considering how we're hitting the caches on the inputs

Comment: @0x534f53 Will same caches be hit even if I use mutual exclusion? What do you mean by "*how we're hitting the caches on the inputs*"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your inner loop jumps all over array `X` with a mixture of strides that varies with 
the outer-loop iteration.  Unless `n` and `d` are quite small,<sup>*</sup> this is likely to produce poor cache usage -- in the serial code, too, but parallelizing would amplify that effect.  At least `X` is not written by the function, which improves the outlook.  Also, there do not appear to be any data dependencies across iterations of the outer loop, which is good.

> **what is the optimal way to split the problem?**

Probably the best available way would be to split outer-loop iterations among your threads.  For `T` threads, have one perform iterations  `0` ... `(N / T) - 1`, have the second do `(N / T) ... (2 * N / T) - 1`, *etc*..

**How could I significantly reduce the execution time of my script?**

The first thing *I* would do is use simple multiplication instead of `pow` to compute squares.  It's unclear whether you stand to gain anything from parallelism.

> - I have already tried utilizing pthreads asynchronously through the use
>     of a global_index that is imposed to mutex and a local_index. [...]

If you have to involve a mutex, semaphore, or similar synchronization object then the task is probably hopeless.  Happily (maybe) there does not appear to be any need for that.  Assigning outer-loop iterations to threads dynamically is way over-engineered for this problem.  Statically assigning iterations to threads as I already described will remove the need for such synchronization, and since the cost of the inner loop does not look like it will vary much for different outer-loop iterations, there probably will not be too much inefficiency introduced that way.

> Another idea is to predetermine and split the array (say to four equal parts) and assign the computation of each segment to a given pthread. I don't know if that's a common-efficient procedure though.

This sounds like what I described.  It is one of the standard scheduling models provided by OMP, and one of the most efficient available for many problems, given that it does not itself require a mutex.  It is somewhat sensitive to the relationship between the number of threads and the number of available execution units, however.  For example, if you parallelize across five cores in a four-core machine, then one will have to wait to run until one of the others has finished -- best theoretical speedup 60%.  Parallelizing the same computation across only four cores uses the compute resources more efficiently, for a best theoretical speedup of about 75%.

---

<sup>*</sup> If `n` and `d` *are* quite small, say anything remotely close to the values in the example driver program, then the overhead arising from parallelization has a good chance of overcoming any gains from parallel execution.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer! I have already tried doing what you described since yesterday but your answer helped me gain more intuition on this particular solution. Great explanation. It worked perfectly.